# MediatR - IRequestPreProcessor - Incorrect type is used for contextual logging

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, mediatr, jetbrains-rider

I'm using MediatR's IRequestPreProcessor to log the requests. However, I'm getting the following warning at `ILogger<TRequest> logger`:

> Incorrect type is used for contextual logging

How do I fix it?

```cs
public sealed class LoggingBehaviour<TRequest> : IRequestPreProcessor<TRequest> where TRequest : notnull
{
    private readonly ILogger<TRequest> _logger;

    public LoggingBehaviour(ILogger<TRequest> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Process(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var requestName = typeof(TRequest).Name;
        _logger.LogInformation("Request: {Name} {@Request}", requestName, request);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace of the exception? I do not recognise that error message

Comment: Based on Jason's clean architecture, the private  ILogger field, isn't with a T type, please see here  https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/Application/Common/Behaviours/LoggingBehaviour.cs

Comment: In addition, have you tried it without the sealed keyword?

Comment: @AviSiboni, but I already added that. I assume that's a bug from JetBrains Rider.

Comment: @DavidG, no stacktrace. It is highlighted by JetBrains Rider. Nothing more.

Comment: Can you try run it with command line, just to make sure isn’t issue with Rider ?

Comment: @AviSiboni it compiles and runs just fine. It's some IntelliSense bug of Rider or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full class type: `ILogger<LoggingBehaviour<TRequest>>`

Source: https://github.com/olsh/resharper-structured-logging/blob/master/rules/ContextualLoggerProblem.md